# Android UI glitch when setting ActionBar color

Tags: android, user-interface, android-fragments, android-actionbar, visual-glitch

Together with friends I have created an Android app and I have a strange issue connected with the UI.

When switching between fragments sometimes the UI tends to scramble, create a glitch displayed below.

[image]

It happens on my Nexus 5 with Dalvik runtime and stock Android and on my friend's Nexus 4 with ART runtime and SlimKat rom. But it is not observable on another Nexus 5 with Dalvik runtime and 4.4.2 (AOSB rom). The weird thing is that it was not happening before I updated to the newest version of the app.

Below is the layout used, where the `main_fragment` is the place I put the `Fragment` with the use of transaction.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I found out that the glitch appears when this line is executed and it does not matter what I put inside the `setBackgroundDrawable` method:

```
activity.getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor(getCurrentTheme(activity))));
```

Does anybody else have this problem? Or maybe someone knows a workaround or how to make it work?

Edit: I need to change the ActionBar color in runtime (changing theme in app settings).

Comment: Set the actionbarcolor through styles/themes, that would make the executed line redundant

Comment: See the official docs here about styling actionbar background: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html#CustomBackground

Comment: @user1281750 It won't work because I need to change the ActionBar color in runtime.

Answer (score 4):

I encountered this problem a few days ago when applying a background color to the ActionBar at runtime. This was on a Nexus 5 running stock Android 5.0, and I had success with the workaround suggested in this reply of this issue: [Issue 1760](https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?id=1760#c8)

The workaround is to disable [Hardware Acceleration](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html) either globally or for the particular Activity where this occurs. There is one more possibility, which is to disable hardware acceleration for a View at runtime, but I'm not sure how to apply this to the ActionBar.

### Disable hardware acceleration globally

**AndroidManifest.xml**:

```
<application android:hardwareAccelerated="false" ...>
```

### Disable hardware acceleration for an Activity

**AndroidManifest.xml**:

```
<application android:hardwareAccelerated="true">
    <activity ... />
    <activity android:hardwareAccelerated="false" />
</application>
```

### Disable hardware acceleration for a View

**At runtime**

```
myView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```